# Finding clashes in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have two columns in a table; Date and Session. Date is in the format dd/mm/yyyy and session can either be 1 or 2.

What I want to do is make a query that produces a table in which, one date that has two or more of the same session. An example will make it clearer:

```
DATE          SESSION
28/01/2015     2
06/02/2015     1
28/01/2015     2
etc...
```

It should return the two rows with 28/01/2015 in since they both have the same Session.

Answer (score 0):

'Date' is a reserved word and should be avoided. I assume that 'Sessions' is text, not number. So try this:

```
SELECT tblTest.MyDt, Count(tblTest.Session) AS CountOfSession
FROM tblTest
GROUP BY tblTest.MyDt
HAVING (((Count(tblTest.Session))>1));
```

Was this helpful?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried it out yet. I will try to do it today.